# Is it correct to write 'valuable asset'?

Tags: meaning

According to this [dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/asset), the word 'asset' already includes a value in its meaning :

> A useful or valuable thing or person:
>
> quick reflexes were his chief assets
>
> the school is an asset to the community

Why is it so common to see, 'valuable asset', 'good asset',  ect.? Do I look in a wrong dictionary or many people get the meaning of the word wrong?

Comment: Where is it stated that it is **necessarily valuable** ? There's no such definition. Please re-read the definitions.

Comment: @Kris An asset must have some measure of some property considered to be of value.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Please review the first definition above.

Comment: @Kris Usefulness is of value. The poor definition implies a distinction, where there is actually quite a degree of overlap.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Hope the significance of *or* needs no emphasis. I am persistent because I know there's more than a strong reason for the use of the phase "useful or valuable" in the definition.

Comment: Give me an example of where an attribute or object etc can be said to be useful but have no value and I'll perhaps believe you. RHK Webster's gives the sense of 'valuable' that clearly overlaps with that of 'asset': **2. having qualities worthy of esteem**. The overlap between 'useful' and 'valuable' is given in the Online Dictionary: **valuable. ... 1. useful ...** And consider how Tim's answer is being upvoted.

Comment: @Kris So an asset does not have to be valuable? Can you please make an example when usage of word 'asset' does not imply that the asset is valuable?

Comment: It's redundant when it's valuable. It's valuable because/when its useful. All assets have value, some are more valuable than others.

Comment: @MasterPJ: Saying that something is "valuable" implies that it not just that its value is non-zero, but rather that its value is *greater than that of typical things in a similar context*.

Comment: The adjective "valuable", when applied in such a context, means "of substantial value".  Technically, an appraiser might use "valuable" in a different sense, to imply that *some* value could be placed on the object, but most English speakers would avoid using it in that sense simply to avoid the confusion.  ("Invaluable" is even more confusing.)

Comment: @supercat Without context, and you don't give any, 'valuable' can mean that the commodity / attribute etc improves the situation from how it would be were the asset not present. Admittedly it _usually_ means 'having considerable value' rather than 'not without value'. But 'not very valuable' is possible.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: There are so many contexts where things could have a value which was non-zero, but insufficiently great to merit particular notice, that in the absence of context the phrase "valuable asset" cannot be presumed redundant.

Comment: @supercat I'm not saying 'valuable asset' is tautologous. In this construction, 'valuable' is constrained to take the 'having a high value' sense Tim mentions (I'd say it was the usual sense). So it's an intensifier here, like 'real' in 'real asset'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Value* sometimes implies 'high value' as in *the town places a value on the school*. In other contexts it is a mere number: a house-clearer will place a value on a shelf of paperback books (because that's his job), but it is likely to be merely nominal. Similarly with *asset*; the assets of a company include staplers and pencils, but if you are called *an asset to the firm* it is implied that you are a valuable asset. *Valuable* itself no longer shares this ambiguity: the meaning 'possible to put a price on' (as opposed to *invaluable*) is hardly used, and the almost invariable meaning these days is 'having a high value'.

Comment: +1, but don't knock staplers.

Comment: Actually, even your paperback example of 'value' involves the concept of 'something [perhaps just about] worth possessing'. A classic example of a non-advantageous usage is 'What is the value of x satisfying the equation ...?'

Answer (score 7):

It is not wrong.

While it is true that an asset by definition must have value, some assets have more value than others. An asset worth a million dollars is more valuable than an asset worth a hundred dollars.

In the light of that, the hundred dollar thing is just an asset, while the million dollar thing is a *valuable* (as in high value) asset.

Answer (score 1):

There are also contexts where an asset is simply something the subject has in possession, not necessarily to their benefit. Consider an idiom *toxic asset* as an example. That said, unless you are working within such a context, simply calling something *an asset* already has positive connotations and implications of benefit and value. While it's not wrong to say *valuable asset*, consider if *asset* would be a more concise way to make your point.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context.  Say you possess a set of assets, one of which is fluency in Aramaic.  In some professions this may be a *valuable asset.*  In other professions, it may be less valuable.

Comment: So an asset does not necessary have to be valuable? Is it more like a skill or an ability? I mean: skill has traditionally positive context (if you know how to do something, it is good ) but in some cases it is not important or can have even a negative effect. A Buddhist monk skilled in meditation would probably not be a good broker (just an example, maybe he would :))

Comment: @MasterPJ..... **Value** is relative.

Comment: If it's of no use/benefit at any time, it's not an asset. If you will need it 10 years down the line, it's an asset.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  I agree with you.  Circumstances can change the assessment.  A Sumo wrestler may consider his great size and strength to be valuable assets.  If he changes profession and becomes a jockey, not only do these previously valuable assets loose their value, they may not be assets at all.

Comment: @Gary's Student Ah, we're into 'who decides on whether X is an asset or not' (philosophy) territory now. I'd say that having something you draw on now or later is having an asset; also, if you have a broken leg that prevents you from sailing on the Titanic, it could be termed an asset.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth...... an interesting example